# Why do webKit browsers render the following with extra padding/margin on the bottom?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

This issue is minor but is bugging me, why do webKit browsers render the following with extra padding/margin on the bottom? is the only way to solve this to specify heights?

```
<div style="background-color:#efefef; width:200px;">
  <textarea style="padding:0px; margin:0px;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Render:
[image]

Comment: This is odd, and I don't know why it happens -- but you can get rid of it by floating the text area inside the parent div. (You'll also have to set `overflow:hidden;` on the parent div).  I'd really like to know a better answer for this, if anyone has one.

Comment: @Lee: Your solution is the best so far, and i've tried many things.

Comment: I just figured it out... See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div style="background-color:#efefef; width:200px;">
    <textarea style="display:block;">asdf</textarea>
</div>
```

Apparently, it has something to do with `<textarea>` being an inline element.  The gap appears to be the area below the baseline.  If you set `display:block;`, it will get rid of the gap.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the height of the text box to match the div? It doesn't look like your telling it a height so it may be using a default height (based on the div).  Just try it, no guarantees but hey it may.